# Write a recursive method int adroit(BSTreeNode oak) which takes the root of a binary search tree and returns the number of right-monogenous nodes

Tags: sorting, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have this as my homework question for APCS. So far I have

```
private Node root;
private int adoitcount;
public int adroit() {
    for(int i = 1; i < count; i++){
        if(root.getRight() == null)
            return adoitcount;
        if (root.getRight() != null) {
            adoitcount++;
            return adoitcount;
        }
    }
    return adoitcount;
}
```

It should be returning 3 when I printout the method but I am only getting 1. I also do not know how to do it recursively, I have never quite understood how to do recursion. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Dan it's Jackson (same class), for starters your for loop isn't doing anything so it's going to the only statement that works (your second if statement) and then immediately returns that value because you put it inside the if statement.

Recursion can be difficult to understand but just think about it like calling the same method again. The trick is to change the output value (after each recursion) so it reaches a return statement, because once anything reaches a return statement it ends all of those methods that are the same. So in this case once OBJECT.getRight == null; occurs we enter a return statement while all other cases enter a recursion which include:

1) OBJECT.getLeft() != null

2) OBJECT.getLeft() == null

3) OBJECT.getRight() != null

This is just an explanation for how the recursion works.

```
public int adroit(Node oak){
    Node current =oak;

    if (current.getRight() == null){
        return totalAdroit;
    }
    if (current.getLeft() != null){
        adroit(current.getLeft());
    }
    if (current.getRight() != null){
        adroit(current.getRight());
    }
    if (current.getLeft() == null && current.getRight() != null)
        totalAdroit++;

    return totalAdroit;
}
```

The first if statement checks to see if the root has a getRight() being null, if so the totalAdroit is 0. The second and if statement checks if getLeft() and getRight() are null, if so it recalls the same method but replaces what was "oak" as the original object with the equivalent of "oak.getLeft()" and goes throughout the if statement again.

Recursion is important because it does not replace the "oak" value with "oak.getLeft()" but in a way it makes a second "oak" object and makes it equal to "oak.getLeft". So now you have in a way 2 oak Nodes both looking for the same thing which is the last if statement. After the recursion method is called the oak object goes to the next method and it continues until the return statement.

Hopefully this helped, if anything it should allow you to finish the HW.

Answer (score 0):

Oh hey, you're in my programming class. Anyways, it's me David, and I came across this, clearly. Well, to be honest, I'm terrible at programming and recursion makes no sense to me, I wonder why, but I'll try my best to explain it with a simple example, since simple examples are easy for me to explain. And I understand simple examples, unlike this homework assignment...

Let's look at this code:

```
public int number(int n) {
        if(n <= 10) {
             return number(n+1);
        } else {
            return n;
        }
    }
```

In recursion, you need some sort of parameter, since the whole point of recursion is to return a value, then place the returned value back into the method, and repeat until you have some  sort of stop code.

So in the first line, I have "public int number(int n); 
In the second line, I'm checking if the value n (let's say n is 0) if n is less than or equal to 10. If n is less than 10, then it will add one to n, making it n = 1; 
My next line is number(n). Well, now that n is 1, the code is basically number(1). This will rerun that number method and us 1. Is 1 smaller than 10? Yes, so we will now add 1 to 1 making n = 2. The code is now number(2). We throw 2 into the method. 2 is smaller than 10, so n = 3, and so on and on until n = 10; 
My else statement is there so it will return a final value, if you add it up, n should equal 11. (If you're wondering why 11, n passes the test when it's 10, so n becomes 11. But, 11 does not pass the test, so it moves to the else statement, and returns n, which again, is 11.

That's my best attempt at describing recursion. You probably get the simpler stuff, but this is just to describe it again. As far as your code for the homework, you don't need a while statement, since recursion in general is a loop. Also, you will need a parameter for the method. I can't fully explain how the recursion works on the binary tree, since i just don't get it, but that's how simple recursion.

Comment: The point of recursion in this homework assignment is to go through every position and see if it has only one child to the right. The recursive part would be checking every position (using the current.getLeft and current.getRight) if it has a right AND left node or if it has no nodes at all. The other part to this recursion is checking if it only has one right connecting node (if (current.getLeft() == null && current.getRight() != null) then you would add 1 to your total. Does that make sense? Again, i'm terrible at explaining this in words.